# Create solution for category attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a goal to create some feature. What I need.

There are two models Products and Category. Products has Foreign key to Category. In the same time different Categories should have different Attributes.

For example:
Category "Cats" has attribute "breed" and Category "Cars" has attributes "model", "mark", "Color" etc.. Attributes should contains list of values. How the best way to create it in Django?

I really haven't any ideas how to make the models design to achieve my goal.

@As a result, I need to create a form in which, depending on the selected category will change the list of available attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As One category has many attributes and there's also possibility that one attribute can be part of many category for example 'color' attribute can be part of 'Car' and 'Truck'. So I think suitable solution is to create many to many relationship table for attribute and category. For how to implement in Django please refer to [Many to Many Field in Django Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)
[image]

Comment: In addition to the **"name"** attribute must contain a list of values. For example the list of car brands, to attribute **"car model"** and colors for the **"color"** attribute. In your circuit is not clear how to manage the values of attributes.